# Oracle compare date

Tags: java, oracle

I have a table with date field in it. User passes month and year. I need to return records where its date has passed year and month.

For example.
Record in table: time:'2016-01-10', time:'2016-01-01', time:'2015-01-01'.
Passed values: year:'2016', month:'01'.
And the return should be first and second records.

How to do it in oracle?

PS. I tried smth like this time>=date'2016-01-01' and time<=date'2016-01-31' but if the last day is not 31, I will get an exception.

Comment: Surely you can find the information you need in Oracle documentation, also online? Search and research and tell us what you found and in what way it was insufficient.

Comment: Look up the last_day function in the documentation. But also check whether your column has any values where the time is not midnight - particularly on the last day of a month - and if so consider what your <= comparison will do then.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [date formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)
If I understand you correct you want something like this

To_char(Your_date_col, 'YYYYMM' ) = yearparam ||monthparam